# Return from a function when making API call (javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I am using the soundcloud API.  I have a function in which I call 

    `SC.get('/tracks', { tags: geotags }, SearchTracks);`

which returns the response object and the error code to the function called SearchTracks.  After calling SearchTracks, how do I get back to the main function that I was in, and how do I return the response object to it?

The API Call is here in plot_soundcloud:

`function plot_soundcloud(coor)
            
{
            var geotags= "geo:lon="+SCQueryPoints.join(" geo:lon=");

            SC.get('/tracks', { tags: geotags }, SearchTracks);

            alert ("return here and do some more stuff");  //this line does not execute
            
}`

it calls this function, but how do I get back to plot_soundcloud?

```
var SearchTracks=function Search(tracks)<br>{
 // assign longitude and latitude<br>
 for (var key in tracks)
     {var lon=tracks[key].tag_list.match(/geo:lon=(.*?\.\d+)\s*/);
     tracks[key].lon=lon[1];      
     var lat=tracks[key].tag_list.match(/geo:lat=(.*?\.\d+)\s*/);
     tracks[key].lat=lat[1];
     }
 return tracks; //I want to be able to use tracks[key].lon in plot_soundcloud
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  The main function has already ended.  If there is something you need to do with the results (or just need to do after the GET is done) you have to do it in SearchTracks.

If SearchTracks needs access to local variables of plot_soundcloud, simply declare  SearchTracks inside plot_soundcloud.

(And a little hint: pick a naming standard for functions and stick to it.  So SearchTracks and PlotSoundCloud, or (preferably) search_tracks and plot_soundcloud.

Comment: Thank you Malvolio, I didn't realize that Javascipt program flow conventions are different than in the older languages.  I tried putting var SearchTracks; in function plot_soundcloud but the program aborts right there.  So I cannot access my plot_soundcloud variables

Comment: @HeatherSpence -- Javascript is *nonblocking*.  It doesn't stop to wait for things like I/O.  But programs don't "abort".  You might have a syntax error, an undeclared variable, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you don't get back.

Implement the more stuff as part of SearchTracks implement a function for doing the more stuff, and have that function be called instead of SearchTracks